# AWS SQS, SNS, Redis, RabbitMQ or something else

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Looking for some ideas/pattern to solve a design problem for an ecommerce ordering system.

I have users that make orders, and customers that process orders, after they have been received.

So let's say a user 1 belongs to customer 1 and I want this order to be pushed only to customer 1 terminal ( web site ). Another user 2 belongs to customer 2, and this order should be delivered only to customer 2 terminal website.

My idea is to store synchronously new order to some db, and then post a message to some kind of a queue. This queue should be monitored by customer's web terminal using ajax pooling, or server sent events, but the biggest question is how to architect these queues, so that orders to customer 1, are only delivered to customer 1, orders to customer 2, only to customer 2, and so forth.

Do I create queues for each customer, do I create pub /sub channel in redis for each customer, and then have specific logic on client to poll only the queue that this client belongs to? Is sns, sqs, redis, rabbitmq or something else suitable for this? The system should be reliable, and order is important.

I assume that polling database for messages, would be an approach, but I am not sure if this is efficient?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ is the best aproach for your problem. You have to create one queue for each consumer and each user will send orders to the queue of that consumer.

Furthermore you don't need to poll the database because RabbitMQ will send the order to your consumer as soon as it arrives to the RabbitMQ broker in an event fashion.

RabbitMQ also lets you mark your messages and queues as reliable and durable so you won't lose messages. And of course, they are delivered in order

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can create a queue for each consumer even in SQS, and use long polling against those queues. I am worried about managing my own rabbitmq server, scalling up and down. I am wondering how big players handle situations like this one. It is a common architecture design request.

Comment: RabbitMQ also has a cluster configuration easy to set. I use it for achieve High Availability and Scalability